Python Sqlite cursor.execute breaks Selenium driver.get
I've got a script that is supposed to pull data from a sqlite database, and then use it in a chrome browser with selenium.
At the moment it will only give me the standard "data:," page in chrome no matter what I do as long as the sqlite "cursor.execute" exists before the "driver.get" in the code.
A working example would be to comment out the cursor.execute in the code below and give dblink, dbuser, dboass an actual value. But that does not work since I need it to pull data from the database.
Would something like sqlalchemy instead of the standard sqlite3 library solve this? Or is there another way to handle the data from the database and pass it to selenium?
   #!/usr/bin/python3
    import os
    import time
    import sqlite3
    from selenium import webdriver
    from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
    
    # Options to run clean kiosk mode and keep the browser alive.
    option = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
    option.add_argument("--disable-notifications")
    option.add_argument('--disable-infobars')
    option.add_argument("--start-maximized")
    option.add_argument("--no-sandbox")
    option.add_argument("--disable-web-security")
    option.add_argument("--ignore-certificate-errors")
    # option.add_argument("--kiosk")
    option.add_argument("--disable-password-manager-reauthentication")
    option.add_argument('--disable-save-password-bubble')
    option.add_argument('--disable-blink-features=AutomationControlled')
    option.add_argument("--password-store=basic")
    option.add_experimental_option("prefs", {"profile.default_content_setting_values.notifications": 2,"credentials_enable_service": False,"profile.password_manager_enabled": False,})
    # Keep alive and disable automation pop-up
    option.add_experimental_option("detach", True)
    option.add_experimental_option("excludeSwitches", ["enable-automation"])
    
    service = webdriver.ChromeService(executable_path='/usr/bin/chromedriver')
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=service, options=option)
    
    # DATABASE = 'assets.db'
    def get_db_connection():
        conn = sqlite3.connect('assets.db')
        # conn.row_factory = sqlite3.Row
        return conn
    
    conn = get_db_connection()
    cursor = conn.cursor()
    entries = list(cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM ENTRIES"))
    dblink = entries[0][2]
    dbuser = entries[0][5]
    dbpass = entries[0][6]
    conn.close()

    
    def opsLogin(link,user,password):
        driver.get('%s' % link)
        driver.implicitly_wait(20)
        username_field = driver.find_element(By.NAME, 'login_username')
        username_field.send_keys('%s' % user)
        password_field = driver.find_element(By.NAME, 'login_password')
        password_field.send_keys('%s' % password)
        login = driver.find_element(By.ID, "submit")
        login.click()
        driver.implicitly_wait(20)
    opsLogin(dblink,dbuser,dbpass)

Gonna try jsonify and see if that might solve my issue.

Print dblink, dbuser, and dbpass after you pull them from the db to make sure that they contain the values that you are expecting. Then print link, user, password inside opsLogin(). Are the values correct in all 3 variables in both locations?

Just tried it and yes it is, it's only driver.get that seems to break after a cursor.execute
